# A datatable rendred with extra line on the top - SgDatatablesBundle

Tags: symfony, datatable, doctrine

I am using SgDatatablesBundle 1.0

The datatable is rendred with a line on the top contain  inputfileds!

I dont know how to remove it ,Please any help

I have follwed this link to use the bundle :

https://github.com/stwe/DatatablesBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/installation.md#your-first-datatable

[image]

my class postDatatable:

```
namespace AppBundle\Datatables;

/**
 * Class PostDatatable
 *
 * @package AppBundle\Datatables
 */
class PostDatatable extends AbstractDatatable
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildDatatable(array $options = array())
    {
        $this->language->set(array(
            'cdn_language_by_locale' => true
            //'language' => 'de'
        ));

        $this->ajax->set(array( 'url' => $this->router->generate('app_homepage'),
            'type' => 'GET'
        ));

        $this->options->set(array(
            'individual_filtering' => true,
            'individual_filtering_position' => 'head',
            'order_cells_top' => true,
        ));

        $this->features->set(array(
        ));

        $this->columnBuilder

            ->add('name', Column::class, array(
                'title' => 'Name',
                ))
            ->add('nbPges', Column::class, array(
                'title' => 'NbPges',
                ))
            ->add('subject', Column::class, array(
                'title' => 'Subject',
                ))
            ->add(null, ActionColumn::class, array(
                'title' => $this->translator->trans('sg.datatables.actions.title'),
                'actions' => array(
                    array(
                        'route' => 'app_homepage',
                        'route_parameters' => array(
                            'id' => 'id'
                        ),
                        'label' => $this->translator->trans('sg.datatables.actions.show'),
                        'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open',
                        'attributes' => array(
                            'rel' => 'tooltip',
                            'title' => $this->translator->trans('sg.datatables.actions.show'),
                            'class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-xs',
                            'role' => 'button'
                        ),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'route' => 'app_homepage',
                        'route_parameters' => array(
                            'id' => 'id'
                        ),
                        'label' => $this->translator->trans('sg.datatables.actions.edit'),
                        'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-edit',
                        'attributes' => array(
                            'rel' => 'tooltip',
                            'title' => $this->translator->trans('sg.datatables.actions.edit'),
                            'class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-xs',
                            'role' => 'button'
                        ),
                    )
                )
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getEntity()
    {
        return 'AppBundle\Entity\Post';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'post_datatable';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the available [options](https://github.com/stwe/DatatablesBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/options.md).

You need to set `individual_filtering` to false to remove the search input fields.